# EditText backspace custom functionality - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a question regarding android studio java. Currently, I have an editText that lets the user insert tags for a post.

The tags appear like this:

"Tag1, tag2, tag3"

When the user press the space button a filter assigned to the editText returns ", " so that space is used to separate different tags. Now, I need to implement a functionality for backspace.

What I wanna achieve is this:
When removing the space, I want to automatically remove also the comma. What's the best way to achieve such functionality?

I'm really lost

Comment: refer to this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextWatcher()` :

```
EditText textBox = findViewById(R.id.textBox);

textBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if (editable.length() > 0 && editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1) == ' ') {
            // Remove acomma if it exists before the space
            if (editable.length() > 1 && editable.charAt(editable.length() - 2) == ',') {
                editable.delete(editable.length() - 2, editable.length() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Official documentation [is here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher).

Also, see further [this](https://www.w3schools.blog/edittext-with-textwatcher-android).